# Liquibase equivalent of beforeEachMigrate in Flyway

Tags: liquibase, flyway

I am trying to find the Flyway's `beforeEachMigrate` equivalent functionality in liquibase. Does liquibase have a way to execute an SQL script before each new migration script is executed?

My current liquibase structure looks like follows.

**application.properties** file

```
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/changelog-master.yaml
```

**changelog-master.yaml** file

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      file: db/changelog/1-initial-schema.sql
  - include:
      file: db/changelog/2-schema-update.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

create something like `db/changelog/00-init.sql`

and put there something like

```xml
<changeSet id="1" author="you" runAlways="true">
    <sql>...or whatever change</sql>
</changeSet>
```

note: use [runAlways](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/changelog-formats.html)

**EDIT:** I'm looking into `beforeEachMigrate` and it executes change before each let's say `changeSet`. There is no equivalent for that in liquibase so far.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto what @bilak said, you can also set the parameter using runOrder in addition to runAlways.

Documentation: To always run a changeset before OR after an update - runAlways/runOrder - https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/changelog-formats.html